# How long are the sides of a quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

The triangle inequality provides a necessary *and sufficient* condition for three numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3$ to be the lengths of the sides of a triangle; there is no triangle unless each $a_i$ is less than the sum of the other two, and if that condition is satisfied, then there does exist a triangle with those sides.

Given positive real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$, what is a necessary and sufficient condition for these to be the lengths of the sides of a plane quadrilateral?

What is the corresponding condition for the four numbers to be the sides of a *convex* plane quadrilateral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each side is less than the sum of the other three.  That allows both convex and concave plane quadrilaterals.
First make one straight side out of $a_1+a_2$ and form a triangle.  Then nudge it out of straight a little either way to get a convex or concave quadrilateral.
Hmm, that won't work if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the longest sides.  Perhaps it is possible if they are the shortest sides.